# finding duplicate row and flagging first row as 1 and remaining duplicate rows 0

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates, row-number

I have below data in my a table,

```
COL1  COL2

A      X  
A      Y  
A      Z  
B      W  
B      W  
C      L  
C      L
```

I want to fetch the above data with a additional flag such as, flag should be 1 for unique column value and first occurrence of duplicate should be 1 and remaining duplicate rows as 0,
Expected output :

```
COL1  COL2   FLAG  
A      X     1  
A      Y     1  
A      Z     1  
B      W     1   -- First occurance  
B      W     0   -- Second occurance  
C      L     1   -- First occurance  
C      L     0   -- Second occurance
```

I know that row_number() over(partition by COL1,COL2) will return count like below,

```
COL1   COL2   FLAG  
A       X     1  
A       Y     1     
A       Z     1    
B       W     2    
B       W     2   
C       L     3  
C       L     3
```

but This is not I want. The second occurrence of same column values should be falgged as 0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MySQL doesn't support row_number. Are you sure you're using MySQL?

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11g

Comment: What is want is very simple - a `case` expression, as in Gordon's answer. Something like `select col1, col2, case row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by NULL) when 1 then 1 else 0 end as flag from.....`

Answer (score 6):

You can try this query.

using `CASE WHEN` expression check rn is or isn't greater than 1

```
SELECT t.COL1,t.COL2,CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END "FLAG"
FROM (
 SELECT *,row_number() over(partition by COL1,COL2 ORDER BY COL1) rn
 FROM T
) as t
```

**Result**

[image]

[Sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6f0237e6737fd4c04ef29ae868ecd70d)

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. Your answer results in flag 1 for first 3 rows and 0 for remaing ( rows given in above question), that is not I want. Please go through the question one more time.

Comment: @muruliss [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7dad5/2) It works (with a few corrections to the syntax).

Comment: @muruliss Could you tell me what I missed?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as a "first row" in a table or a group of rows -- unless you have a column that specifies the ordering.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

This will work:

```
select t.*,
       (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order col2)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from t;
```

If you do not have an ordering column, then you can assign an *arbitrary* row a value of "1" and "0" for the rest.

Incidentally, you misunderstand `row_number()`.  You are confusing it with `dense_rank() over (order by col1)`.  Your expression, `row_number() over (partition by COL1, COL2)` would return:

```
COL1   COL2   FLAG  
A       X     1  
A       Y     1     
A       Z     1    
B       W     1    
B       W     2   
C       L     1  
C       L     2
```

Comment: The OP does not seem to care about "order" - "first" can be **any** row with the same values in BOTH columns. Your solution is correct, but I believe the OP is looking for `partition by col1, col2 order by NULL`. `order by NULL` means order randomly; `row_number()` will still work.